# Weird nonce validation problem

Tags: nonce

I have a front-end form (ie, should work for non-logged-in users) with a nonce - "my-nonce-name". The problem is that it sometimes verifies upon submission and sometimes not, for - to me - no apparent reason.

This is the code used to create the nonce:

```
<?php wp_nonce_field( 'my-nonce-name-action', 'my-nonce-name' ); ?>
```

And this is the code to verify:

```
if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( sanitize_key( $_POST['my-nonce-name'] ), 'my-nonce-name-action' ) ) {
    (do stuff)
    die( 'error: nonce not verified.' );
} else {
    (do stuff)
    die( 'nonce verified.' );
}
```

Interestingly, in all of the different browsers/sessions I've tested, the initially created nonce-value is always this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="my-nonce-name" name="my-nonce-name" value="97a7695f22">
```

Upon the first submission, the field will be present in the POST Array as expected,

```
["my-nonce-name"]=> string(10) "97a7695f22"
```

yet the validation fails:

```
error: nonce not verified.
```

Now, when I go back and reload the page, a different nonce will be created. This time, the nonces will differ across the various browsers/instances. One example - form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="my-nonce-name" name="my-nonce-name" value="fb519b10fa">
```

POST:

```
["my-nonce-name"]=> string(10) "fb519b10fa"
```

Result:

```
nonce verified.
```

Now, since users will usually only submit this form once, it really should work upon first try. I'm really at a loss here, as to a) why the initial nonce is the same across multiple instances for logged-out users, and b) why it doesn't validate in the first case and c) how I can get it to validate when logged-out users submit the form for the first time.

Thanks for any idea!

Comment: Probably an obvious question, but do you have any site caching going on?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! No, no caching in this case.

Comment: I'm curious if you try the functions that https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/ uses, what would happen. e.g. `wp_nonce_tick()` should always be different — I wonder if you have the same output every time on first page load per session?

Comment: I was also under the impression that this would be a time-dependent value. But I echoed out the wp_nonce_tick() return value in two different browsers and the return value was the same: 38510, on the other hand it was also 38510 when a different nonce was verified in a second attempt.

Comment: Looks like I was wrong, then! :) How about wp_get_session_token()? Are you logged in to the same account in multiple browsers when you do this test?